# Are there any other sequence of continuous functions like $x^n$ which converges pointwise to $0$ except at $x=1$ on$ [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, harmonic-analysis, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I was amazed at the beauty of the sequence of continuous functions $f_n(x)= x^n$. It certainly converges pointwise (not uniformly) on $[0,1]$. I want to know what are the characteristics of this particular sequence of continuous functions which give them a peculiar limit function which is continuous almost everywhere on $[0,1]$. How can we construct this type of sequence of functions? Certaily the sequence I want to construct should not be a subsequence of the given sequence and which is eventually different from the above sequence

Comment: In response to the question in the title, it's very easy to construct other such sequences, e.g. by various transformations.

Comment: Which transform? I only know about Laplace transform. Are you hinting towards Dirac delta function?

Comment: $x^n\cos x$ for example

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)$ be any function such that $g(x)\in[0,1)$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and $g(1)=1$. For example,

$$g(x)=x^k$$
$$g(x)=sin\left({\pi x \over 2}\right)^k$$
$$g(x)={x^2+1\over 2}$$
$$g(x)=3x^2-2x^3$$
$$g(x)=6x^5-15x^4+10x^3$$

etc.

Then, the sequence

$$f_n(x) = g(x)^n$$

satisfies your requirements.

Comment: ok. can you give the properties for the polynomials $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ such that $(g(x)+h(x) )^n)$satisfies the above criterion?

Comment: @jaggu This is a separate question. In fact, your question now feels like an XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is your actual question?

Comment: As you are taking sum of multiple polynomials ,I want to know how are you choosing those polyomials?

Comment: @jaggu Where do I take a sum of multiple polynomials? What do you mean?

Comment: are not you summing 3x^2 and -2x^3? are not they multiple (2) polynomials?likewise others too

Comment: @jaggu There's nothing special about them being polynomials and/or summing them. The sufficient condition for $g(x)$ is stated in the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f_n(x) = (x^a)^n $ on $[0,1]$ , where $ a $ is any positive integer.

Take $f_n(x) =( \sin(\frac{πx}{2}) )^n $ on $[0,1]$

Also, take $f_n(x) = (e^{x-1})^n $ on $[0,1]$

Take $f_n(x) =( \tan(\frac{πx}{4}) )^n $ on $[0,1]$

Comment: That is a subsequence only of the given sequence

Comment: @jaggu Still, it is a different sequence.

Comment: I want a sequence which is eventually different and not a sub sequence of the given sequence

Comment: @jaggu Then, you should've mentioned it in the question.

Comment: That should be obvious also question allows only 150 characters

Comment: @jaggu 1) There is no limit on the size of a question. 2) Being obvious is subjective. Stating your question as precisely as possible is much better than hoping that others interpret it the same way you did, and increases your chances of getting an answer that satisfies you.

Comment: sorry I meant the title

Comment: will edit the question shortly

Comment: @lisyarus edited. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $f_n(t)=t^n$,t$\in$[0,1] and you take a continuous g:[0,1]->$\mathbb R$ with g(1)=0(every function g with those conditions)then you can show that for every t$\in$[0,1] $(f_n.g)(t)$-->0 uniformly

Comment: Let me prove this:g is bounded from an M>0(I suppose its M>1 if your M<=1 then you just take a bigger) so $|(g(t))|$<=M for t $\in$ [0,1].Also,take ε>0,g is continuous so you have that there is a δ>0 that $|g(t)|$<ε for t $\in$ (1-δ,1].If t$\in$ [0,1-δ] |fn*g|<=M$(1-δ)^n$<Με(explain why).If t$\in$ (1-δ,1] then $|fng|$<ε<Με.In any case $|fng|$<=Με

Comment: can you tell me what is * here? Is it composition of functions?

Comment: Its multiplication

Answer (score 0):

I'll do you one better and work with a sequence with a pointwise limit that makes sense on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the sequence of compactly supported smooth functions defined by

$$ f_n(x) = \exp(1)\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-(n(1-x))^2}\right).$$

on $\left(1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: ok . How did you find this sequence of functions? Please give me some idea

Comment: please gve me hint

Comment: This is a standard example of what is known as a bump function. Look it up on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Take

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+n(1-x)}.$$

Then $f_n(x) \downarrow 0$ if $x\in[0,1)$ and $f_n(1)=1$. The following figure demonstrates the graph of $f_n$ on $[0,1]$ for $n=2^1,2^2,\dots,2^{14}$, colored in increasing order of frequency.

[image: Figure 1]

---

**2.** Take

$$f_n(x) = \frac{2n}{1+(n(x-1)+\sqrt{2n-1})^2}.$$

Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ if $x \neq 1$ and $f_n(1)=1$. This example is interesting because $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_n(x) = 2n$ diverges as $n\to\infty$. The following figure demonstrates the graph of $f_n$ on $[0,1]$ for $n=2^1,2^2,\dots,2^{14}$.

[image: Figure 2]